# TUITabBarController inside UINavigationController problems

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to add `UITabBarController` as root view of my UINavigation controller. The purpose of that is that I want to make similar navigation as Facebook app: Then user select contact on Contacts tab - pushed view with user details doesn't have TabBar.

So, I have navigation controller, tab bar as a root view or it and couple TableViewControllers inside this `UITabBarController`.

[image: Storyboard]

I have two major issues with that:

1. I can't assign title for navigation bar for root views of tabbar. If I open contact details I have navigation bar title and no tab bar (as I wanted). But if I select Contacts or Favorites - those views have empty navigation bar title. I've tried to set it on viewDidLoad and viewDidApper without any success
2. Even worse issue. When I press Favorites table view insets are broken. first cell is under navigation bar. First loaded tableview (in my case Contact) displayed correctly. Adjust scroll view insets is `YES` for both TableViews.

**Update:**

Solution storyboard (note property "Hide Bottom Bar on the Push" is switched to YES).

[image]

Comment: Can you arrange these the other way around, where the tab bar vc contains navigation vcs?  This is by far the more common arrangement.

Comment: I wanted to hide tab bar on push, but JaanusSiim answered how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also struggling with UITabBarController + UINavigationController issue. When UITabBarController was contained by UINavigationController, content insets were acting really weird.

I would suggest to use navigation controllers inside UITabBarController and when next controller is pushed, set 'hidesBottomBarWhenPushed' on that controller to YES.

This would also solve setting navigation bar title, as navigation controller is closer to view controller. You can just use self.navigationItem.

If you leave it to current setup - UITabController contained within UINavigationController, then you need to modify navigationItem on controllers tabBarController (self.tabBarController.navigationItem). Note that best place for it would be in view controllers 'viewWillAppear' for every controller contained within UITabBarController, as they share one navigation item.